# Ajax request from controller in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, rest

i am trying to use ajax to get data from a server and store it in a cookie. The code below is being built in coodeigniter, and comes from the controller.

```
          $email = $this->input->post('username');
          $pword = $this->input->post('password');
          <script type="text/javascript">
           $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "http://localhost/projects/comp6300Server/index.php/rest/resources/token/username/" + $email + "/password/" + $pword + "/institution/" + inst,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function ($token)
            {
              $this->load->helper('cookie');
              $cookie = = array(
                'name'   => $email,
                'value'  => $token.value()
              );
              $this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
            {
              alert(thrownError);
            }
           });
          </script>
```

The actual return from the server should be an xml file like below, and i want to store the number returned as the value of the cookie.

```
 <xml>
  <item>209273</item>
 </xml>
```

I think my problem is that i cant put jquery code directly in the php controller. However, i dont know how to do the ajax request without the jquery. Can anyone help me?

Comment: first problem is your request is expecting json while server is sending xml

Comment: You're completely blending Javascript and PHP together in this example, which is very *very* broken...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you are expecting JSON, you need to change this to xml

```
 dataType: "xml"
```

Secondly you are mixing JavaScript with PHP, your approach is incorrect.